# How to access private array in a class in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

```
Struct S
{int a,b,c};

class A{
    S myArray[MAX]
    void fillArrayFromFile();
};

class B{
    void printStyle1();
    void printStyle2();
    void printSTyle3();
};

class C{
    void printStyle4();
    void printStyle5();
    void printSTyle6();
};
```

So given that bit of pretend code ...

I want classes B and C  to be able to read information from the array in class A without being able to change the data.

Accessor functions would be exceedingly cumbersome since I would have to write a function for each different output format or else create a temporary struct to hold the data and pass it to the calling class so it can . This doesn't seem like the best solution.

A friend function would give access to members of the class, but not the instance I need to get to (unless I'm misunderstanding friend functions ...)

making the array public would allow classes other than the two I wish to have access to access/manipulate the data.

Comment: friend classes can access your data member as well as methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow clients the ability to examine the contents of the array you can do this with a single member function in `A`.

```
class A
{
    S myArray[MAX]
    void fillArrayFromFile();
public:
    const S* getArrayPointer() const { return &myArray; }
};
```

This has the same effect as allowing them direct read only access.

Comment: Still vulnerable to a `const<*>` cast though. (Yet I don't think anything can prevent this without making a copy)

Comment: @phoeagon `const_cast` is irrelevant here. You can't prevent someone from using it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The formatting doesn't make sense to me ... I see a return of an S pointer, but what's the const doing outside of {} for the definition?

Comment: the `const` on the outside of the function declaration makes it so the it cannot modify any member variables when it is called. It's part of const-correctness. It also requires the function to return by `const` if the type is a pointer or reference.

Comment: I thought that's what the first const did, the one before S*, or did that just say that S* can't change?

Comment: The `const` before `S*` is applied to the return type not to the member function.

Comment: So the trailing one applies to getArrayPointer(), meaning if getArrayPointer were to try to, say, modify the array, it wouldn't be able to?

Answer (score 2):

Add an access function to A which returns a const pointer or reference to the array, or to a specified element in S.

```
const S* getArray() const { return myArray; }
const S& getElement(size_t ele) const { return myArray[ele]; }
```